# Creating a VideoClip of only one frame and Finding the Frame rate of an existing Video

Tags: python, video

I want to create a VideoClip of only one frame of the video. The first frame will do.I am using moviepy. I have tried writing this code:

`dur=1/fps       #fps= frame rate

clip=VideoFileClip("vid.mp4").subclip(0,dur)`

but it did not give me any exact results in case `dur` was a recurring decimal.
Also I need a way to find the frame rate of an existing video.

Comment: You are already using fps to calculate dur so it's not unknown to you?

Comment: i am using fps that is mentioned in the video properties. But i can't do this for a video with unknown frame rate. That is why i need a way to figure out any video's frame rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a clip with `clip=VideoFileClip("vid.mp4")`, the fps is given by `clip.fps`.

If you want to get the first frame as a clip you write

```
clip2 = clip.to_ImageClip(t=0).set_duration(some_duration_in_seconds)
```

But it is unclear what you want ot do with that first frame. Maybe if you explain more about your goal I can give you a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I want to make a clip with the first frame of the video of the exactly same duration as it is being played in the video. This code `clip2= clip.to_ImageClip(t=0).set_duration(some_duration_in_seconds)`   asks the user to set duration of the clip. I want it to be automatically set to the duration of that frame as it is in the original video.

Comment: clip2 = clip.to_ImageClip(t=0).set_duration(1.0/clip.fps) then.